# Как сделать, чтобы переменная типа Calendar не менялась?

Tags: java, android

После того, как я присваиваю переменной `dateAndTime = Calendar.getInstance()`, она начинает изменяться с течением времени. Как мне это исправить?

Comment: Ого... Вроде этого быть не должно. Покажите где и как вы эту переменную используете и как выясняете что она меняется.

Comment: Задекларируйте переменную как `final` и посмотрите что будет при компиляции - компилятор вам подскажет где она может изменяться

Comment: Вы его каждый раз так берете или в переменную сохраняете?

Comment: @Barmaley, нее) 100% ТС берет календарь каждый рах а надо один ращ